# Error : Safari can't open the page because the address is invalid ? Facebook integration

Tags: facebook, authentication, safari, xcode4.6

i am working on integrating fb login to our own application.
Problem is example i downloaded it's working fine,when use the code in my project its getting error

**Note:** I Checked the   **fbapplicationid in .plist**  and in the url page they both are same.

[image]

Comment: use better formatting so that other can understand as well as other who face the issue can also find this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After User authorizes the App. Facebook request the browser to launch the app that requested access. That url is based on App's url schemes ( defined in App's plist). So you need to double check that. Safari shows error because it cannot find the url scheme -> Invalid URL

it is of the form like `fb<myAppId>`.
After that do a clean build of project and run.

Comment: hi shaggy ,u mean i want to edit my plyst id from 123 to fb123 .!!and i always make clean builds to executes this app

Comment: not always! it is done to be sure changes reflect. and yes to fb123

Comment: shaggy ,i made changes what u said before but unfortunately error doesn't solved,any other suggestions

Comment: hi shaggy,finally i solved it,i found what i missed, i added FBid in plist but i didnt mention URLSchema,When i integrated this example first time it automatically generated the URLSchema so i didnt notice that time,after that i created it manually now it exiguted successfully.Thanks for you help man its really encouraging ..:)

Answer (score 5):

Friends ,when ever you are trying FBlogin to your application ,dn't forget to check **.plist**

*Must verify before you exegete*

**1.FBapplication ID**

**2.URLSchemas**