# Safari cannot open page after Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement 3rd party login in a cordova app per the instructions on the firebase site https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova But I'm receiving an error in Safari that "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

I tried a few things, including verifying the info.plist settings like this:
[Error : Safari can't open the page because the address is invalid ? Facebook integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738219/error-safari-cant-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-facebook-int)

or this:
[iphone facebook login safari cannot open the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054118/iphone-facebook-login-safari-cannot-open-the-page)

or even this:
[iphone facebook login safari cannot open the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054118/iphone-facebook-login-safari-cannot-open-the-page)

With the last one, I saw the comment about the simulator and tried it on a device and it still doesn't work.

I'm just trying to perform a test, so the app is very simple.  Here's my plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1234567890</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>myRealApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>fb1234567890</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mysite.myRealApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>ionic.local</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>myRealApp-519f4.firebaseio.com</key>
        <dict/>
      </dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you create an Facebook web OAuth client or a mobile OAuth client? For Firebase Auth Cordova OAuth support, you have to use a web OAuth client.

Comment: I'm using the web OAuth client.

Comment: Did you ever fixed this issue?? I'm facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes to this, I was able to fix this by upgrading firebase to version 3.9. The current version is 4.6.2 which I would imagine, would do the trick as well.

Thanks,
Wayne